# Understanding $SL_3(D)$ where D is a central division algebra

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups

Suppose that $K$ is a non-archimedean local field of positive characteristic and $D$ is a four-dimensional central division algebra over $K$. The group $SL_{3}(D)$ can be embedded as a $K$-form of $SL_{6}(K')$ for some finite Galois extension $K'$ of $K$. Would there be anywhere where I could read more about exactly how this works, as in some kind of description of what the embedding is?

Comment: $D$ has dimension two over $K'$, whenever  $K'$ is a subfield of $D$. Then you can view $D^3$ as a 6-dimensional (left or right) vector space over $K'$. Presumably the elements of $SL_3(D)$ are some kind (one-sided) $D$-module automorphisms of $D^3$, so they are also $K'$-linear automorphisms of $D^3\cong_{K'}K'^6$, and thus matrices.

Comment: But please satisfy my curiosity. What is the definition of $SL_3(D)$? Determinant is an iffy concept when the ring is not commutative. Presumable you look at what happens to the Haar measure or?

Comment: I think it's meant to be defined using the Dieudonné determinant.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dieudonné_determinant

Comment: Isn't this just using the fact that if D is a quaternion algebra over K then D embeds in M_2(K(rt(d)))? (Where d is the value of j^2).